# suppress some messages in rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

When i configure some service with logging in local0.*, i put file to /etc/rsyslog.d/service:

```
local0.*             /var/log/service.log
```

But i see this (duplicate) message in /var/log/messages too. I can suppress it (in rsyslog.conf change string with /message, add local0.none), but i cannot automate it, like "yum install service" with put the file in rsyslog.d.
Can i write something like

```
local0.* ~
```

as second line of my service config? Or any option for disable duplicate messages?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: after string with local0.* i need add

```
&~
```